# How to save NSMutablearray that is present in a class to a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Student.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Subject.h"

@interface Student : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *studentID;
    NSString *studentName;
    NSMutableArray<Subject* > *subjects;
}

@property (copy) NSString *studentID;
@property (copy) NSString *studentName;
@property (copy) NSMutableArray<Subject* > *subjects;

-(Student *)initWithStudentID:(NSString *)ID andStudentName:(NSString *)name;

-(void)addSubject:(Subject *) subject;
@end
```

Student.m

```
#import "Student.h"

@implementation Student

@synthesize  studentName;
@synthesize  studentID;
@synthesize  subjects;

-(Student *)initWithStudentID:(NSString *)ID andStudentName:(NSString *)name {

    Student *student = [[Student alloc] init];

    student.studentID = [NSString stringWithString:ID];
    student.studentName = [NSString stringWithString:name];

    return student;
}

-(void)addSubject:(Subject *)subject{
    if(subjects==nil){
        subjects=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [subjects addObject:subject];


}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setStudentID:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"studentID"]];
        [self setStudentName:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"studentName"]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:subjects] forKey:@"subjects"];
           }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:studentID forKey:@"studentID"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:studentName forKey:@"studentName"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:subjects forKey:@"subjects"];
}

@end
```

Subject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Subject : NSObject
@property  NSString *subjectID;
@property  NSString *subjectName;
@end
```

Subject.m

```
#import "Subject.h"

@implementation Subject
@end
```

Main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Student.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Student *student1=[[Student alloc ]initWithStudentID:@"Nirmal" andStudentName:@"101"];

        Subject *subject = [Subject alloc];
        subject.subjectID=@"S01";
        subject.subjectName=@"PHY";

        [student1 addSubject:subject];

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:student1 toFile:@"/Users/kuzhandaivel/Documents/nirmal.plist"];

        Student *student2=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/Users/kuzhandaivel/Documents/nirmal.plist"];

        NSLog(@"%@",student2.studentID);
        NSLog(@"%@",student2.studentName);
        NSLog(@"%@",[student2.subjects description]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to save NSMutablearray that is present in a class to a file?
The above program throws the below error at line:

```
[aCoder encodeObject:subjects forKey:@"subjects"];
```

at `encodeWithCoder` function present in student.m file.

```
Archiver[4667:102276] -[Subject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006000a0
2016-10-22 20:25:57.738 Archiver[4667:102276] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Subject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006000a0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Subject` also needs to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol just like `Student`.

Every class stored within the root object you are archiving must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: @interface Subject : NSObject<NSCoding>. I added in this way. should I add initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder funtions in the Subject.m file? Please advise

Comment: Yes. The two methods are required for every class that states that it conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: Thnaks rMaddy. I will try it now !!

Comment: Can you please tell me  how to save NSDecimalNumber to the file. 
For the line --> @property NSDecimalNumber *miles i am writing like
 self.miles    = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"miles"] in the initWithCoder method 
and    [aCoder encodeObject:_miles forKey:@"miles"]  in the encodeWithCoder method. But the data is not saved in the plist file. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

All object inside your object hierarchy needs to confirm NSCoding protocol to be able to save to archive.

If you see NSString class

> @interface NSString : NSObject `<NSCopying, NSMutableCopying,NSSecureCoding`>

It implements NSSecureCoding which is subclass of NSCoding. So you need to implement NSCoding protocol on all the child object and child object of child object and so on.
Its basically iterates over all the child object and encode them one by one. So it will fail if you haven't implemented on any of them.

> Archiver[4667:102276] -[Subject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1006000a0 2016-10-22 20:25:57.738
>   Archiver[4667:102276] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Subject encodeWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006000a0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I think this line  says it all.

> [subject encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder]

Comment: Hi Can you please tel me how to save NS

Comment: Can you please tell me  how to save NSDecimalNumber to the file. 
For the line --> @property NSDecimalNumber *miles i am writing like
 self.miles    = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"miles"] in the initWithCoder method 
and    [aCoder encodeObject:_miles forKey:@"miles"]  in the encodeWithCoder method. But the data is not saved in the plist file. Please advise

Comment: It should work fine as NSDecimalNumber->NSNumber->NSValue->NSObject. This is the class hierarchy and it should work fine. Only concern i can say is that you should use self.miles rather than iVar if you have set accessors on top of it. Can you try self.miles and check if its working ?